# SWT usando DATETIME com problema em salvar formato SQL compatível

Tags: java, sql

O problema é o seguinte: Tenho um programa de finanças pessoais que vai cadastrar alguns dados importantes, dentre eles a data do cadastro e data do vencimento. As interfaces do programa são feitas no Eclipse em `SWT`, e estou usando o widget `DateTime`, que utiliza uma instância do calendário nativo do windows e mostra na tela do programa.

Acontece que não consigo armazenar no banco de dados esse formato, pois ele não é compatível com nenhum tipo `SQL`, como `Date` ou `TimeStamp`. Eu já tentei converter esse valor pra `String` e pra `Date`, mas ele não aceita. Alguém tem uma idéia?

Espero ter deixado claro o problema sem a necessidade de postar código, pois é um problema de compatibilidade de formatos `SWT` com `SQL`. Se alguém usa `SWT` ou tem uma ideia de como mostrar um calendário resumido *(dd/MM/yyyy)* na tela, pro usuário acompanhar a data do cadastro e escolher a data do vencimento pra depois salvar no banco, eu agradeço o auxílio.

Comment: Pelo seu comentário na [resposta do Anthony](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66696/4816), a solução que ele deu, funcionou - sugiro que você *aceite* a resposta dele, clicando no sinal de *certo*, no canto superior esquerdo da resposta. É desta maneira que retribuímos a ajuda que a comunidade nos presta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu converteria para um tipo intermediário como `Calendar` (Java <= 7) ou `LocalDate` (no Java 8):

### Calendar:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dateTime.getDay());
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, dateTime.getMonth());
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, dateTime.getYear());
// Em alguns bancos como o Oracle tipo `DATE` pode incluir tempo 
// Em bancos sem resolução de tempo não é necessário zerar os campos
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

### LocalDate

```
LocalDate instance = LocalDate.of(dateTime.getYear(),
        dateTime.getMonth() + 1, // SWT Retorna mes no padrão 0 - 11
        dateTime.getDay());
```

Daí para frente é questão de converter para um tipo `sqlDate` como você faria normalmente.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDateFromCalendar = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()); 
java.sql.Date sqlDateFromLocalDate = new java.sql.Date(Date.from(localDate
        .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()).getMillis());
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, usei o Local Date e funcionou perfeitamente.